# How to create a search field for my data out from phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

I am trying to put in a search filter that makes it so you can enter the lock number and it will return just the fields from the phpmyadmin database that has that lock number associated with it. The file name is dataout.php.

```
 <?php
 $db_host = 'localhost'; 
 $db_user = 'nick'; 
 $db_pass = 'ramon';
$db_name = 'lockout'; ?>

 <link href="lockproject.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <input type="text" name="locknumber" placeholder="Enter Lock Number"><br> 
 <br>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Submit">

   <?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
  if (!$conn) {
  die ('Fail to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());   
  }

  $sql = 'SELECT ID, lock_number, equipment_number, work_order, date_out, 
  supervisor_out, comments_out, date_in, supervisor_in
    FROM form';

  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if (!$query) {
  die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
  }

  echo '<table width="60%" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Lock Number:</th>
            <th>Equipment</th>
            <th>Work Order:</th>
            <th>Date OUT:</th>
            <th>Supervisor Initial OUT:</th>
            <th>Comments/Tradesmen:</th>
            <th>Date In:</th>
            <th>Supervisor Initial in:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
  echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['lock_number'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['equipment_number'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['work_order'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['date_out'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['supervisor_out'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['comments_out'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['date_in'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['supervisor_in'].'</td>
     </tr>';

  }
  echo '
   </tbody>
  </table>';
  mysqli_free_result($query);
  mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckin2.php" target='_blank'>Lock 
   Check 
   In Form</a>
   <a href= "http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckoutbeta.php" 
   target='_blank'>Lock 
  Check Out Form</a>
```

Here is the code for the css file that is attached to it called lockproject.css

```
  {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  }
  h1 {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 120;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  }
  h3 {
  color: #F81B1D

  }

   td,  th {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 14px;
  }

 tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #214CD2;}


 th {
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  }
  body {
  background-color: #4D4949;
  }
  a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #214CD2;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  }


  a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

Comment: Okay, so what **exactly** is your issue? What do you expect to happen? What is happening? Are there any errors being output? We can't help you without more detail

Comment: If this is a php/mysql question we don't need to see the css.  Please remove all unnecessary details.  Your question is Unclear and may be closed; clarify asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using a SQL where statement, a good example is shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

By using a GET request in the HTML form, we can get the value from the field and use it in out PHP script. See: 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Html file:

This will submit the lock number to the file as a get request

```
<form action="dataout.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="lock_number"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP script:

We get the value associated with the GET request and use it in the query

For protection you should use prepared statements. 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, lock_number, equipment_number, work_order, date_out, supervisor_out, comments_out, date_in, supervisor_in FROM form WHERE lock_number = ?";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $lock_number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
 //This while give back a row at a time.
 //This contains only the rows that the WHERE statement gets
}
```

Edited in light of `Patrick Q`'s and `Sam Swift`'s comments.

Comment: The OP is not looking for how to prevent sql injection, rather an answer to the question - this does not attempt to answer the question

Comment: There is still a glaring issue - answers along the lines of `try this [code]` are not helpful, it's like setting a cold man on fire rather than teaching him how to get warm

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Please do not discourage answerers from including prepared statements and bound parameters in their answers.  Answers that lead the OP (and future visitors) down the wrong path are _not_ quality answers.

Comment: @PatrickQ - oh no, I don't want to at all, my issue was that's all the answer was (as shown by rev hist), it brought nothing to the OP's question apart from "Here's a flaw in nothing to do with your question at hand"

Answer (score 0):

What you do is SELECT from the TABLE where the lock number in the table equals the entered input. That's all. Nothing hard about it. Also don't use the die function it's deprecated.

What you're looking for is:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$lock_number = $_POST['lock_number'];

$sql = 'SELECT id, lock_number, equipment_number, work_order, date_out, 
supervisor_out, comments_out, date_in, supervisor_in
FROM form WHERE lock_number = "{$lock_number}",'

}
```

First you check if the button has peen pressed then put the entered input into a variable then query the database based on it. It will return the wanted row.

Answer (score -2):

You need to do 2 thing:

> 1. Put search box in a form tag, submit button should come under form tag.

```
<form id="search-form" method='POST'>
     <input type="text" name="locknumber" placeholder="Enter Lock Number"><br> 
 <br>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

> 2. Now Need to update `$sql` Query with condition. after $sql query, need to check if lockumber value is coming in post and not empty we have to add condition with query as given below.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT ID, lock_number, equipment_number, work_order, date_out, 
  supervisor_out, comments_out, date_in, supervisor_in
    FROM form';

  if (isset($_POST['locknumber']) && !empty($_POST['locknumber'])) {
        $sql .= " where lock_number = '" . $_POST['locknumber'] . "'";
  }
```

Hopefully this can help you to resolve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @SamSwift웃; Reply has been updated. It will be better to post a solution  in place of giving comment to other one. :)